# Is there a SEP token in google translate API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

Is there a SEP token in google translate API?
Or any other predefined tokens in the API?

I hope to know for advanced fine-tuning of google translation model.

Comment: could you elaborate more your requirement? What you're trying to do and what type of tokens you're looking for?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan I want fine-tuning the translation model with two or more sequential sentences. (two or more sentences in one data row) So I am looking for a sentence-separator token which used when translation machine learning model is trained.